# Do different jurisdictions have different specialities?

Tags: ncis, ncis-los-angeles, ncis-new-orleans

I've noticed that between *NCIS* and *NCIS: Los Angeles* the latter seems to me more specialised to deep undercover work as both G and Sam have a number of alternate identities while their office doesn't look as "refined" as the one Gibb's team work out of (not including the op's centre) as if to blend in and not be so obvious that it's a government building

I am wondering if this is really the case and if so what the specialisation of the New Oeleans branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do different jurisdictions have different specialities?

## No.

NCIS as an organisation is, per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naval_Criminal_Investigative_Service)...

> The United States Naval Criminal Investigative Service (NCIS) is the primary law enforcement agency of the U.S. Department of the Navy. Its primary function is to investigate criminal activities involving the U.S. Navy and U.S. Marine Corps, though its broad mandate includes national security, counterintelligence, counter-terrorism, cyber warfare, and the protection of U.S. naval assets worldwide.

It has offices in many locations both in the US, afloat and worldwide.

Each office will deal with the issues arising from it's area of responsibility in it's geographical location.

However...NCIS: Los Angeles concerns a **special division** of NCIS rather than a "standard" NCIS field office.

Again, from Wikipedia...

> The series follows the exploits of the Los Angeles–based **Office of Special Projects (OSP), an elite division of the Naval Criminal Investigative Service that specializes in undercover assignments.**

Answer (score -2):

Ok NCIS is the primary navy department functioning to investigate u.s Navy and Marine corps including national security counterintelligents cyber warfare and any u.s assets world wide.
NCIS Los Angeles is a special elite division (osp) office of special projects naval criminal investigations specializing in undercover assignments.they indicated different assignments and areas which operate in two jurisdictions.